# Your desktop layout for web development and or programming in general

Tags: desktop

I own a Macbook laptop and a 21'' monitor, the first on my left and the second just in front of me. I am in OS X Leopard, using two workspaces to which I switch constantly. On the first (conceptually for regular navigation and communication apps like IRC, adium, twitter, skype) I run Safari on the monitor and the IM, IRC etc in the laptop. As long as the screen on the laptop is smaller and the laptop itself is positioned further my sightsee, I run rather static apps that don't need a lot of interacion since they are most of time idle or showing small updates (like twitter). Then on the second workspace I am running Firefox on my laptop screen and some terminals and vim sessions on the monitor in front. I achieve development and coding being made on the main screen, so every time I want to see changes applied, I move to my left laptop and refresh.

I am quite happy with this setting, but I find some drawbacks, e.g. when I want to use Firebug in Firefox I don't feel comfortable, cause the screen is far on my left showing a lot of code.

So I am considering a stronger use of workspaces and focusing all action on the monitor, leaving the rest of "background" or "static" window apps to my laptop on the left. Then, Firefox would be moved to the first workspace, main monitor. Everytime I would want to see changes on it, I would switch workspaces and refresh. Will that be too much switching?

So I am asking you reddit programmers, hackers, and so: any ideas? which is your preferred layout for daily work?

Comment: You're not asking reddit ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Ubuntu Linux with XMonad WM on 15.6 inch laptop. XMonad is a tiling window manager, meaning it handles positions of windows automatically and maximizes usable space. On first workspace I always have browser full screen, second one - gvim full screen, then I have three terminals tiled - one with ssh to server, one into working directory and one for everything else (eg ipython). Then I have workspace for IM, for thunderbird and two utility workspaces in case I need anything else.

This layout assures that everything is in close reach - I am usually on second workspace with GVIM, but I can change to browser to look through mans or to terminal to test something in one keystroke.

---

About too many switching - bind switching to meta (windows key in my case, I dunno what you guys have on your macs ;) and mousewheel, this allows you to switch fast. Also bind workspace switching to meta - number - this allows to switch without using mouse.

Comment: Can you explain 'bind switching'? With the windows key? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Make a hotkey so that pressing a "windows" key and rolling mouse wheel/thumb buttons will switch screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just one minor point - have you thought about detaching Firebug from the Firefox window? Then you could put it on the other monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use workspaces, every time you swap workspace you brain will execute a context-switch and confusion will hit you. Optimizing workspace is all about keeping things that effect each other together.

Keep things visible.

Comment: If you are used to switching workspaces you won't have this problem. It is impossible to keep browser, IDE and terminals all on quite small laptop screen and alt-tab is just a old alternative to workspaces.

Comment: ok, I just thinks that it's how our brains work. Multiple monitors is the best thing.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately you can't always get multiple monitors :(

Comment: I know. I have only one, life sucks.

Answer (score 1):

My setup at work is nearly exactly like yours, minus having a Mac.  My ideal setup would be to have three monitors:

1. Left-most: the laptop monitor.  E-mail, Pidgin, etc. (utility/communication apps).
2. Middle: one 20-22" monitor to show the results of whatever I'm developing.
3. Right: one 20-22" monitor tilted vertically with the development environment on.  Vertical so I can see a lot of code at once.

Comment: Can you actually plug two additional monitors to a laptop? Mine has only one VGA output for example.

Comment: Depends -- I have a docking station for one of my laptops which has both a VGA out and a DVI out, and another laptop that has both a VGA out and an HDMI out.  I haven't tried it yet, but I think the video cards in each should handle three monitors.

Comment: Matrox DualHead2Go is another solution for plugging two monitors to a laptop: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/
I haven't tried it, but it looks tempting...

Answer (score 1):

I have two monitors: 1x 1208x1024 and 1x 1024x768. I put all of my main programs on the main monitor (firefox, development, installers, most explorer windows, etc.) then put all of my ancillary programs on the right (chat windows, VMs, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I have a 24" monitor in front of me, and a MacBook Pro 17" on my left.
On the 24" I run my IDE and Firefox/Firebug for testing my application. On my left I run terminal for web server log output, Opera for regular browsing, and mail.
I find it valuable to be able to see the log output while I test the application.

Answer (score 1):

4 workspaces..
1 local stuff, 2 work in progress, 3 web stuff, 4 misc/overflow

don't know how to do it any easier

Answer (score 0):

I think a 24" monitor is the best value for the money right now. You can get one for almost nothing, and it gives you a resolution of 1920x1200.

When the price of 30" monitors (2560x1600) drops I will probably replace my 24".

If your employer won't buy you one, buy it yorself. You won't regret :)